# Can I use "Just" at the beginning of a sentence when I want to mean "very recently"?

Tags: grammar

For example can I say "Just a terrorist attack happened in Barcelona" instead of "A terrorist attack just happened in Barcelona" or "Just a guy came and asked about you" instead of "A guy just came and asked about you"? I can use "recently" at the beginning of a sentence in any situation as far as I know. Can't I do the same with "Just"?

Comment: No.  You can say "Just now a terrorist attack happened in Barcelona."

Comment: "Just" at the very beginning of a sentence is generally interpreted to mean "merely".

Comment: @GEdgar Or *A terrorist attack just happened in Barcelona*. The *just* needs to precede the verb it is qualifying; e.g. *I just saw a golden eagle*. There is an informal idiom in Britain, little used, but where a person says, when asked when something occurred "Oh, it happened just". But it is colloquial.

Comment: You will hear "just" at the beginning of a sentence followed by a time reference. In your example - "Just this week, a terrorist attack happened in Barcelona"  Or "Just yesterday I saw someone with a Joe Franklin in 2020 sticker on his car"  In those cases 'just' means 'merely' however I bet that is how 'just' got it's adverbial use.  ('I just now saw a bird' might have became 'I just saw a bird' )?